# window.alert("msgg"); not working in vs code shows unexpected alert

Tags: lightning-web-components

[image]

```js
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class BottonClick extends LightningElement
{
    fun() 
    {
        var msgg = "message for user";
        window.alert(msgg);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of native APIs, use LightningAlert, LightningConfirm, and LightningPrompt modules to create notifications from your Lightning web components. The window.alert(), window.confirm(), and window.prompt() native APIs will no longer be supported cross-origin. Modules create modals that work similarly to their API counterparts and work cross-origin.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-alert/documentation